# timestamp with timezone issue with TZR vs TZH:TZM

Tags: oracle, timestamp, jdbc, timezone, goldengate

I have a Hibernate with Oracle JDBC based application inserting/updating into the following column;

```
COLUMN_A TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT systimestamp NOT NULL
```

but while it automatically appends timezone, it uses `TZR`, e.g. `UTC`, and weird thing with this data type in Oracle is that, it retains the format of timezone from insertion when we select it without any formatting, [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417100/timestamp-with-timezone-retains-timezone-format)

With this said, we are utilizing Golden Gate that is replicating this data to MongoDB, but afaik it requires these timestamps to contain only `TZH:TZM` formatting, so I have this issue where one side blocked by Oracle JDBC, where insertion is done with `TZR`, and one side blocked by Golden Gate where data is expected with `TZH:TZM`

Are there any way to handle this issue? Can I not forbid a certain formatting for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` ? Using `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` works for `SELECT` formatting, but it is not usable for Golden Gate I was told. Also for `INSERT` case I was able to utilize `default` value of the column, and using `systimestamp` does insert with `TZH:TZM`, but for `UPDATE` case, I am unable to achieve this. Totally stuck!

I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412424/update-column-to-default-value-without-specifying-it-in-spring-data-jpa) with focus on application side of this issue. I am wondering if there is anything that can be done in DB side?

Comment: GoldenGate is a Oracle product, so I would be **very** surprised if it would not have native support for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I know, and it is perplexing, but I heard from our Oracle support person, there is support, but with a not-so-small cost for every `TZR` to `TZH:TZM` mapping, which is done twice for every row

Answer (score 0):

You could define your table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_A (
    COLUMN_A  
        TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
        DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE '+00:00' 
        NOT NULL,
        CHECK (EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM COLUMN_A) = 'UNKNOWN')
    );

Table created.

INSERT INTO TEST_A VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM +00:00', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZH:TZM'));

1 row created.

INSERT INTO TEST_A VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM UTC', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR'));

>> INSERT INTO TEST_A VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM UTC', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR'))
Error at line 11
ORA-02290: check constraint (SYS_C00241787) violated
```

Or you create a table with trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_B (
    COLUMN_A  
        TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
        DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE '+00:00' 
        NOT NULL
    );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BUIR_TEST_B
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TEST_B
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM :NEW.COLUMN_A) <> 'UNKNOWN' THEN
        :NEW.COLUMN_A := :NEW.COLUMN_A AT TIME ZONE TO_CHAR(:NEW.COLUMN_A, 'tzh:tzm');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

However, I don't believe this would be a proper solution. You may face issues when you work with time zones having daylight saving times.